# Failed to deploy artifact to web app getting this error

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

I am trying to connect Intellijj with Azure so that I can create the web app from Intellijj and it will deploy on Azure but somehow I am getting this issue.

I am able to create resource group but somehow not able to create webapp

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I was choosing wrong region due to that I was facing this issue. I have changed my region to "central US" from "WEST US" and it did work for me.